# Ruby object blank? method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Can someone explain in details this Object method (I mean syntax used here :empty? ,  !!empty? and !self) :

```
def blank?
  respond_to?(:empty?) ? !!empty? : !self
end
```

Or maybe advise good book to read on topic.

Comment: You might want to add some context about where you saw this?

Comment: https://github.com/feedbin/refresher/blob/master/lib/core_ext/blank.rb#L12

Comment: "Or maybe advise good book to read on topic." – The syntax of Ruby is decribed for example in the [ISO Ruby Language Specification](http://iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=59579). Symbol literals are described in section 8.7.6.6, method calls in 11.3.1, `self` in 11.5.4.8.4, and `!` in 11.2.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> if `self` has got method `empty?` then return `double not empty?` otherwise return `single not self`.

`not` (`!`) is an idiomatic way in Ruby to convert any object into Boolean

`single not` (`!`) returns `false` for any `truthy` and `true` for any `falsey` object.

`double not` (`!!`) returns `true` for any `truthy` and `false` for any `falsey` object.

Falsey objects in Ruby are `nil` and `false`, any other objects are truthy.

So. Essentially `respond_to?(:empty?) ? !!empty? : !self` checks if current object has defined method `empty?` and returns true if this method returns anything truthy or false in case of falsey response. If `empty?` is not defined it will always return false if self is not `false` or `nil` (any falsey object).

Answer (score 1):

> I mean syntax used here :empty? , !!empty? and !self

- `:empty?`: this is a `Symbol` literal
- `!!empty?`: this consists of 2 parts:

  - `empty?`: a receiverless argumentless message send
  - `!` syntactic sugar for sending the message `!`, i.e. `!foo` is equivalent to `foo.!`
- `self`: the literal special variable `self`

Answer (score -1):

If something is empty, then it's blank. If it's not empty, then it's not blank. If it doesn't know whether itself is empty, it's considered not blank.

Answer (score -2):

def blank?
  respond_to?(:empty?) ? !!empty? : !self
end

defines blank put into question
(pointless indent) respond_to function attribute empty question it, and is that not not empty question it, checked by self within module. 
the end